# Espresso CursorAdapter: click on the first item

Tags: android, android-espresso

I can't click on the first item of my `Listview` backed by a `CursorAdapter`. 
Here's what I tried:

```
onData(is(instanceOf(ContactsListFragment.ContactsAdapter.class)))
    // .inAdapterView(withId(android.R.id.list))
    .atPosition(0)
    .perform(click());
```

... and here's what I get:

> com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.PerformException:
>   Error performing 'load adapter data' on view 'is assignable from
>   class: class android.widget.AdapterView'. at
>   com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:67)
>   at
>   com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:57)
>   at
>   com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:40)
>   at
>   com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:159)
>   at
>   com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:90)
>   at
>   com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:73)
>   at
>   com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.DataInteraction.load(DataInteraction.java:135)
>   at
>   com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.DataInteraction.perform(DataInteraction.java:112)
>   at
>   .test.ui.activity.ContactsListActivityTest.testShouldSendResultsBackToMailActivity(ContactsListActivityTest.java:21)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
>   at
>   android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
>   at
>   android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
>   at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
>   at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
>   at
>   android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
>   at
>   com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.java:167)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No data found matching: is an
>   instance of
>   .ui.activity.delivery.contacts.ContactsListFragment$ContactsAdapter
>   contained values: <[Data:
>   android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@b312ecd8 (class:
>   class android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner) token: 0,
>   Data: android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@b312ecd8
>   (class: class android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner)
>   token: 1, Data:
>   android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@b312ecd8 (class:
>   class android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner) token: 2]>
>   at
>   com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.action.AdapterDataLoaderAction.perform(AdapterDataLoaderAction.java:80)
>   at
>   com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:119)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I believe this has been fixed, as I no longer have this issue. Do you still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will be addressed in next version (Espresso 1.2). See related issue: https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=69

Comment: Could you please update the issue link? Since the android-test-kit project moved somewhere else the link is not working anymore.